# How to logout of Ubuntu One using OAuth URL?

Tags: ubuntu-one, ubuntu-one-api

I am new to Ubuntu one, and I have implemented **Ubuntu One OAuth** to access data via the Ubuntu One API using **OAuth 1.0a** and its works fine for me. But how can I logout from Ubuntu One using OAuth URL? I am trying to search inside documentation of Ubuntu One site, but I can't get solution.

I am trying to find the URL that I request to server and server logout currently login user and send back success logout response to my website.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: … and a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently an API to allow applications to invalidate the OAuth tokens they have requested.

Users can revoke any tokens they have issued from the following URL though:

https://one.ubuntu.com/account/

The `Devices` section of the page will have an entry for each token that has been issued.  Clicking the `Remove Device` button next to the relevant token will revoke access.